# How to batch create number folders using CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, batch

Is there a way to batch create multiple number folders using cmd in Windows 8.1 64-Bit?

I need something that'll create multiple number folders without using the following `md` command:

```
c:\users\user\desktop> md 1, 2, 3
```

I need something more like that'll make, per say "make folders 1-10" and I have those 10 folders after running the command.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is:

```
 FOR /L %N IN (1,1,5) DO md "newdir_%N"
```

[Documentation](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

Here is a script which makes a lot of directories: https://gist.github.com/krowe/ef10bbc9ae9e39924b7d

Answer (score 0):

`l` switch in `for` is for looping through given numbers, so if don't want to create `newdir_1`, `newdir_2` and so on, but *named* folders, you can put the names in a separate file - `folder.txt`, line-by-line like that:

- movies
- music
- documents
- pictures
- animation
- flash

and then use the `f` switch

```
for /f %a in (folder.txt) do mkdir %a
```

note that if you want to create a script, ie `.bat` file, instead of executing the command directly you have to put an extra `%` in that code before the `a`'s (local variables inside the loop) in order to make it work